# Is there a way to rename empty header CSV file converting to JSON in Python without pandas?

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert a CSV file to JSON but there is a header in my csv that is empty. Is there a way to name it when outputting it to JSON?

Example data

```
 ""     Calories     Fat     Sodium
Bread     100         10        23
```

I got this code from geeksforgeeks

```
import csv 
import json 
  
  
# Function to convert a CSV to JSON 
# Takes the file paths as arguments 
def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath): 
      
    # create a dictionary 
    data = {} 
      
    # Open a csv reader called DictReader 
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 
          
        # Convert each row into a dictionary  
        # and add it to data 
        for rows in csvReader: 
              
            # Assuming a column named 'No' to 
            # be the primary key 
            key = rows[''] 
            data[key] = rows 
  
    # Open a json writer, and use the json.dumps()  
    # function to dump data 
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) 
          
# Driver Code 
  
# Decide the two file paths according to your  
# computer system 
csvFilePath = r'Names.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'Names.json'
  
# Call the make_json function 
make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

I did this and it gets the first row, but i'm not sure how to rename it when i output it to JSON.
It appears as `"":"Bread"` in the JSON file.

```
key = rows['']
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help!

Edit: Expected output

```
 {
   "Food": "Bread",
   "Calories": "45",
   "Fat (g)": "0",
   "Carb. (g)": "11",
   "Fiber (g)": "0",
   "Protein": "0",
   "Sodium": "10"
 }
```

Comment: can you post the expected output json format

Comment: sorry just did! @Kenan

Comment: im getting `KeyError: ''` at `key = rows[''] ` where rows is an `OrderedDict`

Comment: I just noticed that the code creates a dictionary, because I want to import the JSON to mongoDB and have it shown as multiple document. This code makes it being only 1 document. Is there a work around to this?

Comment: I did rows.pop('Drink') = rows[''] and key = rows['Drink'] works for me after that @Kenan

Comment: oh so your all good here now, this question can be closed?